# Jquery .attr and .prop delete the attribute in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, attr, prop

Very odd bug where the following script completely deleted the Value attribute instead of leaving it alone if the replacement variable (in localStorage) is not found.

My html:

```
<form>
<input class="xfield" type="hidden" name="source" value="x111" />
</form>
```

The JS

```
<script>

     var thecode = localStorage.getItem("xcode");
     if (thecode != "undefined" && thecode != "null") {
      $(".xfield").attr("value",thecode);
}

</script>
```

Basically, if the xcode item is found in localStorage everything works great and the default value is replaced. However, if xcode is not found in localStorage, the result ( and only in Chrome it seems, Firefox works fine and leaves things in default ) is that the value attribute is completely erased.

I have tried using `.prop` instead as well as wrapping it in `$(window).load(function(){` but nothing works. Any idea what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `$(".xfield").val(thecode);`?

Comment: Could it be that you use "null" and "undefined" as strings, while they are keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to check for `undefined` or `null`, then check for `undefined` or `null`, not `"undefined"` and `"null"` (which are neither `undefined` nor `null`). :-)

```
var thecode = localStorage.getItem("xcode");
if (thecode != undefined) { // Loose != works for both undefined and null
    $(".xfield").attr("value",thecode);
}
```

But `getItem` won't return `undefined` (it's required to return `null` if the key doesn't exist, and a string [or other storable, like a canvas] if it does), so:

```
var thecode = localStorage.getItem("xcode");
if (thecode !== null) {
    $(".xfield").attr("value",thecode);
}
```

If the code will always be non-blank in the case you care about, you can just test `thecode` directly:

```
var thecode = localStorage.getItem("xcode");
if (thecode) {
    $(".xfield").attr("value",thecode);
}
```

That'll set it for any truthy value. `undefined`, `null`, and `""` are all falsey (as are `0`, `NaN`, and `false`, but you won't get those back from `getItem`).

Comment: Doh! Thank you for the comprehensive breakdown here, its working now!

Comment: So here's a weird thing: I used the same working code on a different site, and now it doesn't work again. Simply will leaves the input value as the page default despite the item being saved in local storage. The only  major difference I can think of here is that this other site uses lazy loading. Can that or something like it prevent the localstorage from being retrieved somehow?

Comment: @Epleroma: No, but you need to be sure the relevant element exists as of when you're running the code. For instance, in the above, if you run the code before there are any `.xfield` elements, then it's a no-op. The elements have to exist *when you call `$()`* in order to be found by `$()`.

Comment: OH yeah that I understand. The exact form style is used in the second site, the xfield class is there as is the value attribute, but it's not being modified. Given that the item shows as being in localStorage, there issue must be with `localStorage.getItem("xcode")` not working or the null check having an issue. There is also an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function which may be playing a part, but not sure how...

Comment: OK, problem solved. For some bizarre reason, this brand new WP theme was running Jquery 1.1... so of course it was mystified by functions form 1.6+

Answer (score 3):

Because `"underfined" !== undefined` and `"null" != null`

```
if (thecode!==null) {
    $(".xfield").val(thecode);
}
```

Comment: Yup, this works, for some reasons I did not realize I had a string in there.